# Conditional resolver in plugins sbt

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to exclude our snapshot repositories for the release build in sbt.

Therefore I thought of a environment variable or system property to control the stage I'm in, since I want to use ivy range syntax (e.g. '[1.0.0,)' ) for released versions of our own libraries and don't want to include SNAPSHOT versions of these libs.
This does not compile:

```
resolvers += {
  val res : Seq[sbt.Resolver] = stage match {
    case "dev" => Seq("Our Artifactory snapshots2" at "https://bla/artifactory/snapshots/")
    case "release" => None
  }
  res
}
```

Is it possible to have conditionally added resolvers in sbt?
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I came to a solution, which is not very nice... I just add the releases a second time in the 'release' case:

```
resolvers += {
  val res : Seq[sbt.Resolver] = stage match {
    case "dev" => Seq("Our Artifactory snapshots2" at "https://bla/artifactory/snapshots/")
    case "release" => Seq("Our Artifactory release" at "https://bla/artifactory/releases/")
  }
  res
}

// here the releases repository is already added...
resolvers += "Our Artifactory release" at "https://bla/artifactory/releases/"
```

Comment: I came to a much nicer solution now: I just use sbt -Dsbt.repository.config=.... and specify a respositories file without snapshots repos for building the release. (so no conditionals are needed in the build.sbt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(stage).collect {
  case "dev" => "Our Artifactory snapshots2" at "https://bla/artifactory/snapshots/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a way more elegant solution.